# can not ssh to another Docker Container docker-compose

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker image which i am using as my git server, i have all my data in it. then i have a database container where i need to clone data from my git docker server.

my docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  git-server:
    image: git:latest
    build:
      context: git
    ports:
      - "22:22"

  my-db:
    image: my-db:latest
    build:
      context: db
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    links:
      - git-server
```

for git docker i am only creating git repos only.

```
FROM kinogmt/centos-ssh:latest

......

RUN mkdir /home/git/dashboard.git
WORKDIR /home/git/dashboard.git
RUN git --bare init && git --bare fetch git@bitbucket.org:****/******.git
.......
EXPOSE 22
```

and in my database dockerfile i am cloning that repo.

```
From centos:centos7

.......
RUN git clone git@git-server:dashboard.git
.......
```

when i run docker-compose build

it says

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname git-server: Name or service not known
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: You have to use network mode bridge in both services.

Comment: i am already making my containers communicate without using network mode bridge by only using their name. 
as my ui is communicating to db by only using it's name

Comment: What docker ps shows to you? Can you manually ssh to the git-server from host level? Did you log in into my-db container to see what is it going on? Did you ping the container one from the another using docker container IPs?

Comment: docker ps shows dockers running but these dockers stop so i can not ssh to those

Answer (score 2):

At build time, containers are not attached to the bridge network (nor are they connected to volumes). If you need container to container networking, you need to move that workflow into your entrypoint or command you run when the container starts.

---

Commands executed with a `RUN` in the Dockerfile are performed at build time. When docker is building your image, it does so without networking to other containers, without volumes mounted, and without any dependencies on other containers. It simply takes the previous state from the prior line, creates a temporary container that runs that `RUN` command, and captures the resulting layers. So attempts to use container-to-container networking will fail because the other containers do not exist at build time. Builds should be reproducible and independent from external artifacts when possible, so this needs a redesign.

As a redesign, I'd personally remove the git clone from your image steps and include the code in the repo where your Dockerfile lives. Do any checkouts before starting the build. This has the advantage of keeping any secrets to log into a private repo out of your image. Then inside your build, you would just do a `COPY` of the files into your image instead of a git fetch.

The other option if there's a need for container-to-container communication for your process is to run a script in your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` that runs any steps you need when the container is run vs when the image is built.

Comment: i did not understand what you are saying. kindly elaborate the last sentence. "command you run when the container starts"

Comment: He means that the the domains in docker network are available in the moment when there are started not during building the containers. Building the containers is done before the system is started and the internal domains are set.

Comment: Also, he means that you need to customize the command that starts the container, something like this: `CMD /command.sh`, and put in that script your `git clone` and your previous command.